# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be an instance of

Tags: php, laravel

Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of App\Models\User given, called in D:\xampp\htdocs\backend\e-commerce\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard.php on line 384 ----
I have this problem please help me 
MY Model Page

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

My Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Mail\UserRegisterMail;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;


class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function login(){
        return view('user.login');
    }

    public function register(){
        return view('user.register');
    }

    public function registerPost(Request $request){
        $request->validate([
            'ad' => 'required|max:60',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'şifrə' => 'required|confirmed',
        ]);
        $request->flash();
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->ad,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->şifrə),
            'activation_code' => Str::random(60),
            'active' => 0
        ]);
        Mail::to($request->email)->send(new UserRegisterMail($user));
        // auth()->login($user,true);
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }

    public function activation($code){
        $user = User::where('activation_code',$code)->first();
        if(!is_null($user))
        {
            $user->activation_code = null;
            $user->active = 1;
            $user->save();
            return redirect()->to('/')->with('message','Qeydiyyatınız tamamlandı');
        }
    }

    public function loginPost(Request $request){
        $request->validate([
            'email'=>'required|email',
            'şifrə'=>'required'
        ]);
        if(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$request->email,'password'=>$request->şifrə],$request->has('xatirla')))
        {
            return redirect()->intended('/');
        }else{
            return redirect()->route('register');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add `activation_code` and `active` fields in ` protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];` on model. I am not sure but This may be solution. I hope work.

Comment: I tried and add $fillable array this parameter but didn't change result

Comment: do you know which page you triggered this error? or which method?

Comment: is it `loginPost` method?

Comment: yes problem is loginPost method

Answer (score 2):

Change extends Model to extends Authenticable.

in your Model

Comment: Hey, while I think this will probably help, it may make your answer a bit better to explain why that would help and what the difference is.

Answer (score 0):

Add and change below lines for your `User` model:

Add:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
```

Change:

```
class User extends Model
```

to

```
class User extends Authenticatable
```